# Share Screen in Zoom Meeting on Mac Does Not Show All Windows

Tags: mac, zoom-meeting

While in a zoom meeting, a mac user clicks "Share Screen," under the Basic tab reports seeing a few Safari pages and "Desktop 1" as an option, they select it, and click "Share." This results in a Safari window being shared. Other application windows are not shared. For example, if they open their Zoom app, it cannot be seen over the share screen.

How does a mac user share their entire screen, with all application windows, over a Zoom call?